# how can I add records through a query in access?

Tags: ms-access

Before I remade this simple database, I was able to perform a query and update and insert new records from that query. I can no longer do this and can't figure out why.

I'm not very knowledgeable with access so any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a feeling that this may have something to do with the auto number column that no longer exists. Basically, it wouldn't allow me to change the data type after I had entered data into the table. I needed to do this to preserve the primary key as they match the client's records and cannot be changed.

Comment: This is very vague.  What steps are you taking to try to perform a query?  What happens when you try?

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to insert records?

Comment: And what error message do you get when you try to change the data type? It is nearly always a bad idea to delete an autonumber field (column) as it is nearly always the unique key.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you have a query that used to work (and insert records in a table) and now doewsn't work anymore? Can you post the SQL of the query and the structure of the table that you are inserting in? That will make it a lot easier for the rest of the world to help you.